# How to sort DIV alphabetically with JQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I need to sort DIVS depending on last name in div member-name.

It must compare only last name and not first name.

Also I must place it in footer or header because i am on Wordpress. I think JQuery is already loaded.
Thanks a lot

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="member-img"><a #POST_LINK#><img src="IHC_AVATAR" alt=""/></a></div>
       <div class="member-content">
            <div class="member-name"  data-lastname="IHC_LAST_NAME"><a #POST_LINK#>IHC_FIRST_NAME IHC_LAST_NAME</a></div>   
    </div>
</li>
<li>    
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="member-img"><a #POST_LINK#><img src="IHC_AVATAR" alt=""/></a></div>
       <div class="member-content">
            <div class="member-name"  data-lastname="IHC_LAST_NAME"><a #POST_LINK#>IHC_FIRST_NAME IHC_LAST_NAME</a></div>   
    </div>
 </li>
<li>  
    <div class="team-member">
      <div class="member-img"><a #POST_LINK#><img src="IHC_AVATAR" alt=""/></a></div>
       <div class="member-content">
            <div class="member-name"  data-lastname="IHC_LAST_NAME"><a #POST_LINK#>IHC_FIRST_NAME IHC_LAST_NAME</a></div>   
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: here it works without adding JS in settings but when adding jQuery it does not work anymore ...https://jsfiddle.net/xo5nopyx/

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap everything in a container, for example in a `div` with class `.container`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="team-member" ...
```

And then slightly update the JS code you provided to sort the content of `.member-name` instead of `.title`.

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.member-name').sort(function(a, b) {
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/4/

Please check the closing tags of `.team-member` divs in your code. I fixed them in the jsfiddle.

Comment: thanks i think i have updated my question when you answer. I need to only sort by LAST NAME...

Comment: well that raises some questions.. what do you mean with _last name_? for example, it can't be just the last word. what if my name is "Carlo Maria De Rossi"? in this case, the last name is "de rossi", which is the last 2 words

Comment: yes you right...If it helps i can add with php a separator like * for example, that must be hidden after the sorting

Comment: if you can manipulate the output, why don't you put the last name before the first one (Doe John)? that would solve the problem. Another solution is to have a markup like `<span class="firstname">John</span> <span class="lastname">Doe</span>`

Comment: thanks have updated the html that i have and i think @rawsun solution is good , using data-lastname , don't you think ?

Comment: for the moment it does not work with the HTML structure i have (with ul li...)

Comment: here it works without adding JS in settings but when adding jQuery it does not work anymore ...https://jsfiddle.net/xo5nopyx/

Answer (score 0):

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yapu9a6m/9/) for order your html in base  memeber-name text:

```
<div  id="ordena">
<div class="team-member">
<div class="member-img">
    <div class="member-content">
    <div class="member-name"><a  href="#" target="_blank">John Doe</a></div>    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="team-member">
<div class="member-img">
    <div class="member-content">
    <div class="member-name"><a  href="#" target="_blank">John Boe</a></div>    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="team-member">
<div class="member-img">
    <div class="member-content">




 var elms = [], 
cloned = $('.team-member:eq(0)');
$('.team-member .member-name').each(function(){
elms.push({name: $(this).text(), lastname:$(this).text().split(' ').splice(1).join(' ')} );

});
function sortByLastName(a,b) {
  if (a.lastname.toLowerCase() < b.lastname.toLowerCase())
    return -1;
  if (a.lastname.toLowerCase() > b.lastname.toLowerCase())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
elms.sort(sortByLastName);
$('#ordena').html('');
for(var i=0; i<elms.length; i++){
cloned
  .clone()
  .text(elms[i].name)
  .appendTo("#ordena");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  is it possible without using ordena ? It's true that there will be a problem with name like John Fitzgerald Kennedy. If it helps i can display a separator like John Fitzgerald * Kennedy

Comment: yes the last name will have copuosed, then you'll need to use a regex or any to obtain the last name, and change ordena like you want @Pipoo

Comment: @Pipoo is update post for last names like you told and chage ordena

Comment: thanks have updated the html that i have and i think @rawsun solution is good , using data-lastname , don't you think ?

Comment: more easy for you sure, but i like think how would be done, not the final solution

Comment: for the moment it does not work with the HTML structure i have (with ul li...)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you only want to do with last name then you should get last name from backend in separate variable.
So with HTML5 tag i have modified just little structure.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="title" data-lastname="blastname">World blastname</div>
        <div class="description">text1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="title" data-lastname="alastname">hello alastname</div>
        <div class="description">text2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <div class="title" data-lastname="dlastname">Lorem dlastname</div>
        <div class="description">text3</div>
    </div>
</div>

    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.title').sort(function(a, b) {
        return 
    String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('lastname').toLowerCase(), 
       $(b).data('lastname').toLowerCase());
    });

    var container = $(".container");
    container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    $('body').append(container);
```

Hope it helps :). If you want to use html same structure then will take time and lots of efforts using js regx.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157675/discussion-on-answer-by-rawsun-how-to-sort-div-alphabetically-with-jquery).